# .net core decoded JWT claim type doesn't match the ones used while generation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm generating a JWT token in .net core 3.1 like so

```
    private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_authenticationSettings.Secret);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(_authenticationSettings.AuthTokenValidityInDays),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

And in my unit tests I'm trying to test it like so

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Authenticate_With_Valid_CredentialsAsync()
    {
        var tokenString = await _sut.Authenticate(new User 
        { 
            Username = "test",
            Email = "test@fakemail.com",
            FirstName = "Someone"
        });
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        Assert.True(jwtHandler.CanReadToken(tokenString));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenString);
        Assert.Equal("test", token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    }
```

The first `Assert` passes however the second one fails because of a null reference exception. I've inspected the code and looked at the username claim which is of type `nameid`. It seems like the value of the key `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` during the tests instead of `nameid`.

Can someone help explain what's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot more digging around I finally found the answer. So what I needed to do was something like this (which gets a `ClaimsPrincipal` which can be queried with static types)

```
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("my-super-secret-test-key")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature).Key,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var user = handler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

        Assert.Equal("test", user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
```

Comment: You could use `user.FindFirstValue` too.

Answer (score 1):

`ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is always the same, the SAML claim including the namespace. However, that doesn't mean that `CreateJwtSecurityToken` will use that string value to present the claim in JWT.

You can use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.OutboundClaimTypeMap` to get the mapping between `ClaimType` (which comes from SOAP identities) to the the value used in JWT.